# How to select specific data from my mondoDB dataset

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I would like to know how you would select only specific data to send through to my state, as at the moment it is sending everything and I only need things like 'firstname', 'lastname', email etc.

Here is what I have for my backend call in NodeJS:

```
// @route   GET api/users
// @desc    Get Users
// @access  Public
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await Users.find()
      .limit(1500)
      .populate('type_id', ['description'])
      .populate({
        path: 'squad',
        select: ['squad_id', 'squad_name'],
        populate: {
          path: 'consultant',
          select: ['firstname', 'lastname'],
        },
      })
      .populate({
        path: 'agent_id',
        select: ['firstname', 'lastname'],
      });
    res.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

[image: Data in MongoDB]

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand well your question you can use `select()` method from `mongoose` (I'm assuming you are using mongoose viewing your code).

`select()` works as the same way in this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cZxsRwcHD2U).

You run a query and then select which fields do you want to get into the response.

The proper way to code it is as follows:

```js
query.select({ field1: 1, field2: 1 });
//or
query.select('-field1');
//and many other ways
```

Docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select)

For your question, something like:

```js
var query = await model.find().YourMethodsHere().select({firstname:1, lastname:1, email:1})
```